# Sort the XML based on node value using <xsl:sort> issue

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I tried to sort the XML based on the value for given xml. In this xml i need sort based on educational_details {DR,PDR,MSC,BSC}. I have use . please see the sample below.

Input XML :-

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <Person>
       <document>
         <studentname>ACM</studentname>
         <educational_details>MSC</educational_details>
       </document>
       <document>
         <studentname>ACB</studentname>
         <educational_details>BSc</educational_details>
       </document>
       <document>
         <studentname>ACP</studentname>
         <educational_details>PDR</educational_details>
       </document>
       <document>
         <studentname>ACC</studentname>
         <educational_details>DR</educational_details>
       </document>
     </Person>
```

I have tried as shown below.

XSL:-

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:param name="pOrder" select="'DR,PDR,MSC,BSc'" />
        <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*">
                    <xsl:sort
                        select="string-length(
                                         substring-before(
                                            concat(',',$pOrder,','),
                                            concat(',',name(),',')))" />
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Out put

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <Person>
       <document>
         <studentname>ACM</studentname>
         <educational_details>MSC</educational_details>
       </document>
       <document>
         <studentname>ACB</studentname>
         <educational_details>BSc</educational_details>
       </document>
       <document>
         <studentname>ACP</studentname>
         <educational_details>PDR</educational_details>
       </document>
       <document>
         <studentname>ACC</studentname>
         <educational_details>DR</educational_details>
       </document>
     </Person>
```

expected out put :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <Person>
       <document>
         <studentname>ACC</studentname>
         <educational_details>DR</educational_details>
       </document>
       <document>
         <studentname>ACP</studentname>
         <educational_details>PDR</educational_details>
       </document>
       <document>
         <studentname>ACM</studentname>
         <educational_details>MSC</educational_details>
       </document>
       <document>
         <studentname>ACB</studentname>
         <educational_details>BSc</educational_details>
       </document>
     </Person>
```

Comment: Your method makes no sense to me. It probably doesn't matter, since it doesn't produce the required result anyway. But could you explain the **logic** behind the requested sort order? A "sort based on educational_details" would sort the records **alphabetically**, ending up with {BSc, DR, MSC, PDR} - or the opposite (descending) order.

Comment: Note also that your input XML example is invalid due to missing root element.

Comment: @ michael.hor257k, here I'm not sorting based on alphabetically. I want to sort based on educational_details DR,PDR,MSc, BSc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thnink you want something alike

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:param name="pOrder" select="'DR,PDR,MSC,BSc'" />

        <xsl:variable name="vSequence" select="tokenize($pOrder, ',')"/>

        <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="root">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="document">
                    <xsl:sort
                        select="index-of($vSequence, educational_details)" />
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

That transforms

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
       <document>
         <studentname>ACM</studentname>
         <educational_details>MSC</educational_details>
       </document>
       <document>
         <studentname>ACB</studentname>
         <educational_details>BSc</educational_details>
       </document>
       <document>
         <studentname>ACP</studentname>
         <educational_details>PDR</educational_details>
       </document>
       <document>
         <studentname>ACC</studentname>
         <educational_details>DR</educational_details>
       </document>
</root>
```

into

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root><document>
         <studentname>ACC</studentname>
         <educational_details>DR</educational_details>
       </document><document>
         <studentname>ACP</studentname>
         <educational_details>PDR</educational_details>
       </document><document>
         <studentname>ACM</studentname>
         <educational_details>MSC</educational_details>
       </document><document>
         <studentname>ACB</studentname>
         <educational_details>BSc</educational_details>
       </document></root>
```

Comment: When i try to convert i got following javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Could not find function: tokenize

Comment: Your question is tagged as XSLT 2.0 and any XSLT 2.0, like Saxon 9 or IBM WebSphere, surely supports the `tokenize` function. If you want to use XSLT 2.0 then you can't use the XSLT 1.0 processor built-in into the SUN/Oracle Java JRE, you will need to switch to Saxon 9. So my answer assumes XSLT 2.0.

Comment: is this logic worked before the transformation or after the transformation? or when it sort the value?

Comment: The sorting happens during the transformation, when `root` element nodes are processed with their matching template then the `apply-templates` with the `sort` ensures that the `document` child elements are processed according to the order you have specified in the sequence of values.

Comment: But when i try to transformed the same XML but the i want output xml i  need to change the element and value name. some think like  <Stu_educational_details tc ="1">Bachelor of Science</Stu_educational_details> i have done the logic to Change the element and value. After that it didn't short the value.

Comment: Please post a new question with details about that new problem.

Comment: sure. i'll post it soon.